# How can I filter objects in my model to only show those of my ForeignKey user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to filter objects in my `view.py` to only show items (in my case Buckets) owned by Users.

I implemented the code below in my original Model [my `model.py` code is at the bottom of post]

```
    class PostObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(status=Bucket.owner)
```

But I'm not sure if that is the correct procedure to list all items?

Here is the `view.py` where I'm trying to filter data by User aka `owner`. Users should ONLY be allowed to view their own items. (I will deal with permissions later)

```
class BucketList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Bucket.objects.all() #INSERT FILTER HERE
    pass
```

Here is the model I'm referring too.

```
class Bucket(models.Model):

    options = (
        ('personal', 'Personal'),
        ('social', 'Social'),
    )


    class PostObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(status=Bucket.owner)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buckets')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=options)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True) 
    stock_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stock_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=6),size=10)

    objects = models.Manager()
    postobjects = PostObjects()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def total_stocks_calc(self):
        self.stock_count = Bucket.objects.aggregate(Sum('stock_list', distinct=True))
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("bucket:bucket-view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.stock_list
```

To re-state my question, how can I filter objects owned by users in `class BucketList` for their private view only?

UPDATE:

```
from django.db.models import Q

from rest_framework import generics
from bucket.models import Bucket
from .serializers import BucketSerializer

class OwnerOrUserFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):

    queryset = Bucket.postobjects.all() # wondering if you didnt write this for brevity reasons or because its not need due to the class?
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(owner=request.user) |  #do I not need to change one of the filters too request.owner?
            Q(users=request.user)
        )


class BucketList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Bucket
    filter_backends = [OwnerOrUserFilterBackend]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `get_queryset` method and filter with `self.request.user`:

```
class BucketList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Bucket
    
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super.get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            owner=self.request.user
        )
```

For an API view, it probably is however better to define a filter, and then use this over all the API views where you want to apply this:

```
class IsOwnerFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(owner=request.user)
```

Then you can use this in your `ListCreateAPIView` with:

```
class BucketList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Bucket
    filter_backends = [IsOwnerFilterBackend]
```

The advantage of this is that if you have other views that require the same filtering, you only need to add the `IsOwnerFilterBackend` as `filter_backend`.

Another filter could include both the owner and the `users` as people who can see the `BucketList`:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class OwnerOrUserFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(owner=request.user) |
            Q(users=request.user)
        )
```

then we thus filter with this filter:

```
class BucketList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Bucket
    filter_backends = [OwnerOrUserFilterBackend]
```

Comment: Thank you! this makes a lot of sense, I was wondering If I can use more than one filter using your method? I have updated my post with a specific example based off your answer.

Comment: @Dre: what is `request.owner` here? You can indeed use something like `owner__in=[user1, user2]`, but here the problem is that `request.owner` does not exists. You thus need something else to determine the "other" user.

Comment: owner is the creator of the bucket. Users are other users that will have permissions to view the bucket.

Comment: @Dre: so you want both the `owner` and the users in `user` to view the `Bucket`?

Comment: Yes that is the idea that I had in mind when constructing the model and view. I know I'm missing other parts to make it possible but just laying down the groundwork for now.

Comment: @Dre: see edit. Normally then users can see `Bucket`s for which they are the `owner` or in the `users`.

Comment: I have updated my post with your code and two small questions. Thank you so much for the help.